# Adding the year to the date on the blogs

Tags: 7, nodes

So, I've gone through making a view called `BlogPage` and a content-type of `BlogEntry` probably ten times now. I've created both in the simplest ways I can, and I've tried to narrow down what is causing my page to look the way it does, and I think it must be my theme. I am using the `Visia` theme I have purchased.

Simply, I've created the view, content of type blog-entry, newest first.

I've also added: Sort Criteria: Content: Post Date(desc).

I do love the look of the blog, but the year is not listed in the date of posting. Is there any way to do this? Is this a setting I can't find? Is this being caused by my theme?

[image: A View of my BlogPage]

**UPDATE:**

I've tried using the "Fields" option, but I can't find the "Date Format" option. This is the screen I have:

[image: Fields Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the date format in *Regional and Language Settings* to match your preference:

https://www.drupal.org/node/71106

Then (assuming you are displaying fields rather than full/teaser nodes) select the date format you require from by editing the field settings in views

[image]

And specifying which of the predefined (or custom) date formats you would like to use:

[image]

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, yet I've never used "Fields" and I can't seem to find this screen for "Field Settings." Sorry, I am terribly new to Drupal.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I am on this same page now, yet I do not have a "Date Format" option under the "Create A Label" as your picture shows..

Comment: I've provided a screenshot of the screen I have